# Forcing Git user to set e-mail address in working copy

Tags: git, git-config

Apparently it's possible to force a Git user to add an e-mail address for each new repository using the following `gitconfig` settings:

```
git config --global user.email "(none)"
git config --global user.useConfigOnly true
```

Which I have done. My `gitconfig -l` output (truncated):

```
core.symlinks=true
core.autocrlf=true
core.fscache=true
color.diff=auto
color.status=auto
color.branch=auto
color.interactive=true
help.format=html
diff.astextplain.textconv=astextplain
rebase.autosquash=true
http.sslcainfo=C:/Program Files/Git/mingw64/ssl/certs/ca-bundle.crt
diff.astextplain.textconv=astextplain
filter.lfs.clean=git-lfs clean -- %f
filter.lfs.smudge=git-lfs smudge -- %f
filter.lfs.required=true
filter.lfs.process=git-lfs filter-process
credential.helper=manager
core.autocrlf=true
core.eol=native
user.name=David Wright
user.email=(none)
user.useconfigonly=true
```

But it does not seem to be working. I am able to commit without setting an e-mail address. The e-mail address that is listed in the commit (oh wonder) is "(none)".

I am using `git version 2.13.0.windows.1`.

I wanted to do this because I am using two different accounts on the same computer. I was able to achieve a similar setting for applying different ssh-keys in my `ssh-config` file:

```
# github account
Host github.com
Port 22
HostName github.com
User git
IdentityFile <file>
```

But apparently there is no such possibility for git itself.

Anyway, I would like to be able to enforce that I have to set a user e-mail address for each repository, and I would like this to be part of my **global** gitconfig. I am aware of a possibility to do this with pre-commit hooks, but as far as I know this hook needs to be copied to each repo after cloning, this is not what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [documentation of `git config`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-config#git-config-useruseConfigOnly) explains:

> **user.useConfigOnly**
>
> Instruct Git to avoid trying to guess defaults for `user.email` and `user.name`, and instead retrieve the values only from the configuration. For example, if you have multiple email addresses and would like to use a different one for each repository, then with this configuration option set to `true` in the global config along with a name, Git will prompt you to set up an email before making new commits in a newly cloned repository. Defaults to `false`.

On Unix-like systems (Linux, macOS etc), when `user.email` is not set, Git attempts to produce an email address by concatenating the OS user name, `@` and the host name.

By setting `user.useConfigOnly` to `true` this behaviour is suppressed and Git uses only the value of `user.email` it finds in the [configuration files](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-config#FILES), if any.

Since you have configured `(none)` as `user.email`, Git uses it as the committer email address.

Use `git config --global --unset user.email` to remove it and Git will start asking you to enter an email address (or at least will complain about `user.email` not being set) for every repository (new or existing) that does not have `user.email` set.

Comment: It's fascintating how easy solutions can be, even though I spent hours trying to figure out what I did wrong. Other sources that I have been looking at said that setting `user.email` to `"(none)"` was what I had to do. Thank you, explicitly unsetting the e-mail address worked, despite the fact that I'm running windows.

Comment: However, git didn't know the option `-g` and the command `unset`, I had to use `git config --global --unset user.email`

Comment: `--global --unset` is the correct way. It was my mistake in the answer; I fixed it now. Thank you for pointing that out.